# Cylinder rotation problems

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a cylinder on a plane that is rotated on the x-axis by 90, putting it on its side.

What I would like is for the cylinder to rotate left and right on the y-axis and move forward and back.

The issue I'm having is that the following code rotates pressing left or right fine at first then the x-axis changes and the cylinder takes off or rolls.

Here is my code:

```
public class ForwardBack : MonoBehaviour {
    // speed variable
    public float speed;


    public KeyCode pressLeft;
    public KeyCode pressRight;
    public float rotationSpeed;
    private int count;
    private int error;
    public bool Follow = false;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {
        speed = 5f;
        rotationSpeed = 50f;
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

        transform.Translate(0f, speed*Input.GetAxis("Vertical") * Time.deltaTime, 0f);

        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.back * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
        if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
        {
            transform.Rotate(Vector3.forward * rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
        }
    }

    void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("A") && count == 0)
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            count++;
            Follow = true; 


        }

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("B")&& count == 1)
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
            count++;

        }

        if (other.gameObject.CompareTag("C") && count == 2)
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);


        }
    }

    //private void endGame()
    //{
     //   break;
    //}

}
```

Comment: It would be useful if you explain what is the correct and unexpected behaviour. You will get help if you are able to accurately explain the issue.

Comment: The cylinder represents a train I would like to move it forward and rotate it around a plane.   Problem with the code is that when you start moving up and down and rotate left or right the cylinder begins to roll.  Making turning the cylinder difficult

Comment: Try adding Space.Self as a last parameter in transform.translate,

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean but will have a play now. thank you

Comment: I have re described the question hope it makes things clearer

Comment: if you want to rotate on Y-axis, why are you use Vector3.back and .forward ? Seems like you rotate on x-axis this way

Comment: prob getting confused on my axis I created a cylinder rotated 90 so it laid on side to resemble a train,  the code above moves it forward and back wards and rotate left/right so train can move around.  but the issue I have is if you hold leftor light it tips up and takes flight also the cylinder rolls making movement hard.